# Solving $2\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\tan\frac{x}{2}\right)=\sin^{-1}\frac{2\sqrt{ab}\sin x}{\left(b+a\right)+\left(b-a\right)\cos x}$

Tags: trigonometry

$$
2\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\tan \frac{x}{2}\right)=\sin ^{-1}\frac{2\sqrt{ab}\sin x}{\left(b+a\right)+\left(b-a\right)\cos x}
$$

I know within inverse of trigonometric function we have the value.
How Do I solve this.

my approach for this solution was:
1st:
$$
\sin ^{-1}\dfrac{2\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{b}}\tan \dfrac{x}{2}}{1+\left( \sqrt{\dfrac{a}{b}}\tan \dfrac{x}{2}\right) ^{2}}
$$
$$
\sin ^{-1}\dfrac{2\dfrac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}\tan \dfrac{x}{2}}{1+\dfrac{a}{b}\tan ^{2}\dfrac{n}{2}}
$$
$$
\sin \dfrac{2\sqrt{a}\tan \dfrac{x}{2}}{\dfrac{\sqrt{b}\left( b+atan ^{2}\dfrac{x}{2}\right) }{b}}
$$
$$
\sin ^{-1}\dfrac{2\sqrt{a}\tan \dfrac{x}{2}\sqrt{b}}{b+atan ^{2}\dfrac{x}{2}}
$$

$$
\sin ^{-1}\dfrac{2\sqrt{ab}\tan \dfrac{x}{2}}{b+atan ^{2}\dfrac{x}{2}}
$$

$$
\sin ^{-1}\dfrac{2\sqrt{ab}\dfrac{\sin \dfrac{x}{2}}{\cos \dfrac{x}{2}}}{b+a\dfrac{\sin ^{2}\dfrac{x}{2}}{\cos ^{2}\dfrac{x}{2}}}
$$

$$
=\sin ^{-1}\dfrac{2\sqrt{ab}\sin \dfrac{x}{2}\cos \dfrac{x}{2}}{\cos ^{2}\dfrac{x}{2}b+asin ^{2}\dfrac{x}{2}}
$$

After this I have tried to approach using

$$
\sin ^{2}\theta +\cos ^{2}\theta =1
$$

formula but could not reach the Right Hand Side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the next step of your attempt: $$\sin ^{-1}\dfrac{\sqrt{ab}\sin x}{b\left(\frac{1+\cos x}{2}\right)+a\left(\frac{1-\cos x}2\right)}$$ using half-angle formula.

The result follows immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\tan A=\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\tan\frac{x}{2}$$ and
$$\sin B=\frac{2\sqrt{ab}\sin x}{(b+a)+(b-a)\cos x}$$

You wish to show $2A=B$. Calculate

$$\sin 2A=2\sin A\cos A=2\frac{\tan A}{\sec^2 A}=2\frac{\tan A}{1+\tan^2 A}$$

so substtitute your value for $\tan A$ into this expression and simplify using $$\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}=\frac{1-\cos x}{1+\cos x}$$

Comment: Is there a way to reach Right Hand Side using my approach?